# Get an element based on a change of another element (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
    <tr class="my-field my-field-color-picker" data-name="background_colour" data-type="color_picker">
        <td class="my-input">
            <input type="text" class="wp-color-picker"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my-field my-field-wysiwyg" data-name="text_block" data-type="wysiwyg">
         <td class="my-input">
                <iframe>
                  <html>
                    <body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body">
                         some text
                    </body>
                 </html>
               </iframe>
          </td>
    </tr>
```

I am able to get the text input with `class="wp-color-picker"` thanks to another thread using `$('tr[data-name="background_colour"] input.wp-color-picker')`

When this text input has a change of value. I want to change the background color of `<body>`

`<body>` is inside an `iframe` inside a `tr` element with `data-type="wysiwyg"` which is on the same level as `tr` with `data-name="background_colour"`

It's a bit of a mess so I hope this makes sense.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rk3fcjkb/19/

Comment: please post a JSFiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr[data-name="background_colour"] input.wp-color-picker').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"]').find('iframe').contents().find('body').css({
      background: $(this).val()
    });
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/eq8tcxbj/)

> PS: Accessing stuff inside iframe can get very nasty.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work for me and your demo link doesn't seem to work? Yeah, it definitely can get very nasty but this might be the only way to go, unfortunately. Thanks!

Comment: I'm positive it works. Type a color in the input field. (something like red)

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle? That jsbin site doesn't seem to want to load for me. :(

Comment: Dhijraj, I hate to bother you but maybe you can help out with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901732/change-background-color-of-body-element-inside-an-iframe
Been bashing my head trying to figure this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the iframe first and then from there go to the `body` tag:

```
$( ".wp-color-picker" ).keyup(function() {
    $('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"] td iframe').contents().find("body").css("background-color","blue");
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmne5e93/1//)

Note: For `change` to trigger you need to un-focus the input element, if you want it to do it right away change it on `keyup` instead.

Comment: There are plenty of other iframe's in the page. So I don't think that would work as I only want that specific textbox to change the background of the body of the iframe that is on the same level as the textbox (`.wp-color-picker`)

Comment: @renny Alright, I didn't know that. I'll edit my answer accordingly. is `data-type="wysiwyg"` unique?