# Change background color of body element inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have the following code:

```
    <table id="first">
       <tr class="my-field my-field-color-picker" data-name="background_colour" data-type="color_picker">
          <td class="my-input">
            <input type="text" class="wp-color-picker"> 
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="my-field my-field-wysiwyg" data-name="text_block" data-type="wysiwyg">
          <td class="my-input">
             <iframe>
                <html>
                  <body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body">
                       some text
                  </body>
                 </html>
               </iframe>
          </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <table id="second">
      <tr class="my-field my-field-color-picker" data-name="background_colour" data-type="color_picker">
         <td class="my-input">
            <input type="text" class="wp-color-picker"> 
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="my-field my-field-wysiwyg" data-name="text_block" data-type="wysiwyg">
          <td class="my-input">
              <iframe>
                  <html>
                    <body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body">
                         some text
                    </body>
                  </html>
              </iframe>
          </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
```

On load, I would like to change the `background-color` to all `body` elements (which is inside an `iframe`) to be the value of whatever is in the text input that is in the same `tr` level as the parent `tr` of the `body`.

So I need to get all `body` elements inside `tr['data-type="wysiwyg"] iframe` and then set that `body` elements css background to the value of the closest `tr['data-name"background_colour"]` siblings `input.wp-color-picker`.

Hope this makes sense. iframe is in the same domain.

UPDATE: I am able to target the correct `body` but now I need to figure out how to get the text input value that's in another `tr` but the same level as the parent `tr` of `body` and use that as the body's background-color.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pgr8wzqb/9/

Comment: Looks like a simple selector? what have you tried so far?

Comment: iframes are problematic for javascript which isn't in them. lose the iframe and load its contents via ajax instead

Comment: so you're saying, iframe inside #first will change based on text input in #first and the same will happen inside #second as well ?

Comment: yes that is true. the value of the text input is already there when page is loaded.

Comment: I think Mr Pete's last comment answers it perfectly.

Comment: Why don't you look at my answer to get the right input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only work if the iframes are on the same domain but you can try:

```
// change the selector to match your iframes
$("iframe").each(function() {
   // you seem to need to load the iframe first otherwise the change will revert to any style sheet
   $(this).load(function () {
       // get the body tag inside the iframe and set the css
       $(this).contents().find('body').css('background-color', 'red');
   });
});
```

You will also need to fix your html, `tr` can only be a child of a `table`, `thead` or `tbody` tag, not a `div`

Having seen your fiddle, it is the invalid html that is spoiling your selector:

```
$('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"]').find('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color', 'red');
```

will work if you change your wrapper div tags to table tags - with the invalid html, jQuery won't pick up on any `$('tr[data-type="wysiwyg"]')` and as you don't have a source for the iframe, you don't need to wait until it is loaded

[Fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgr8wzqb/10/)

Comment: yeah, i noticed that too. thanks for pointing that out. now i just need to change the "red" to the the correct corresponding text input value.

Comment: You could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pgr8wzqb/11/ (type red into the textbox, obviously this would change depending on how you get the colour into the textbox)

Comment: The value of textbox is already there when the page loads, not something that is entered in.

Comment: Ah ok, try this then https://jsfiddle.net/pgr8wzqb/12/, or this one is if your table structure has multiple inputs and iframes in it: https://jsfiddle.net/pgr8wzqb/13/

Comment: Thanks Pete. Very very helpful. Ended up going with this based on yours: https://jsfiddle.net/pgr8wzqb/14/

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the document.domains need to be the same and I'm not sure why you have `<tr>`s in a div, nor what the point of using an `iframe` is in your case, but:

```
$('.wp-color-picker').on('change', function () {
    var color = GetValueFromColorPicker();
    var iframe = $(this).parent().parent().find('iframe');        
    $(iframe).contents().find('body').css('background-color', color);
});
```